# Android и Visual Studio?

Tags: android, ide, java, visual-studio, c++

Вопрос простой: кто нибудь пробовал собрать и дебажить нативный андроид из-под Visual Studio? Если да, то как? И как обстоят дела с Java-кодом андроида из-под Visual Sudio?

P.S. Какие есть альтернативы эклипсу для С++ и Java под андроид?

Answer (score 4):

Дебажить можно. Сам не пробовал, но статьи встречал. Почитайте, например, [тут](http://ian-ni-lewis.blogspot.com/2011/01/its-like-coming-home-again.html).

Для Java тоже разрабатывается решение (можно было писать код, собирать приложение, была подсветка синтаксиса, в каком состоянии сейчас - не знаю), можно посмотреть на [www.vsadt.com](http://www.vsadt.com/).

Как по мне, так лучше действительно перейти на IDEA, если Eclipse не устраивает. Больше времени VS будете настраивать, чем работать :)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [IDEA Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html)

Comment: Там есть поддержка дебага C++ под андроид?

Comment: Не видел... не уверен. Думаю, такой код надо минимизировать насктолько, чтобы ничего дебажить было не нужно.

Comment: Фишка в том, что 90% кода проекта это С или С++, но есть и Java завязки.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы так хотите кодить в Visual Studio то можете попробовать MonoDroid.
Ну а кроме эклипса и IDEA есть еще NetBeans.

Comment: А причем тут MonoDroid? Я же не на С# пишу.

Comment: Ну вы так акцентировали внимание на этой IDE, что я подумал вам в ней привычней и вы хотите начать проект в ней. Но видимо у вас уже готовый проект =)